# How to access CRM Form Javascript Web Resources from within IFrame?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2015

I have a html web resource that I'm displaying on the Lead Entity Form.  The html page utilizes some JS web resource files.  The js files define global namespace variables:

```
if (typeof (myNamespace) == "undefined") { myNamespace = {}; }
myNamespace.CommonLib = { ... }
```

Before 2015 Update 1 was installed, I could access these JS namespaces using `window.parent.myNamespace`.  After the 2015 Update 1 installation, the namespace is no longer accessible from the Web Resource.

I'm guessing this is because of the new Script Engine that caches IFrames:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Is there any way to access the web resources from the form from within the IFrame under the new Turbo Forms Engine?

Answer (score 0):

The supported way of accessing javascript web resources for IFrame pages is to have the html webresource reference the javascript web resources directly.